# Custom projection in GeoServer

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, well-known-text, pyproj

I am trying to create a [custom projection in GeoServer](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/crshandling/customcrs.html), but I see nothing (from the logs, neither in the SRS_list) coming out.
The projection I'm trying to create is a Mercator for Mercury.

I start from the following proj4 string:

```
+proj=merc +a=2439700 +b=2439700 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs
```

Then, in Python, I use [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/) to convert it to WKT:

```py
>>> from pyproj.crs import CRS
>>> merc = CRS('+proj=merc +a=2439700 +b=2439700 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs')
>>> merc.to_wkt()                                                                                                   
'PROJCRS["unknown",BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",DATUM["unknown",ELLIPSOID["unknown",2439700,0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]],PRIMEM["Reference meridian",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]],CONVERSION["unknown",METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",ID["EPSG",1024]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["False easting",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]'
```

Which I then append to my GeoServer's `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/data/user_projections/epsg.properties` as:

```
90000000=PROJCRS["Mercator / Mercury", \
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown", \
        DATUM["unknown", \
            ELLIPSOID["unknown",2439700,0, \
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1, \
                    ID["EPSG",9001] \
                ] \
            ] \
        ], \
        PRIMEM["Reference meridian",0, \
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433, \
                ID["EPSG",9122] \
            ] \
        ] \
    ], \
    CONVERSION["unknown", \
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", \
            ID["EPSG",1024] \
        ], \
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0, \
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433], \
            ID["EPSG",8801] \
        ], \
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0, \
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433], \
            ID["EPSG",8802] \
        ], \
        PARAMETER["False easting",0, \
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1], \
            ID["EPSG",8806] \
        ], \
        PARAMETER["False northing",0, \
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1], \
            ID["EPSG",8807] \
        ] \
    ], \
    CS[Cartesian,2], \
    AXIS["(E)",east,ORDER[1], \
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1, \
            ID["EPSG",9001] \
        ] \
    ], \
    AXIS["(N)",north,ORDER[2], \
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1, \
            ID["EPSG",9001] \
        ] \
    ] \
]
```

I then restart GeoServer but *nothing* comes out in the logs (no error) neither in the Demos/SRS_list.
It is like the projection/file is not read.

Clearly, I'm missing something obvious here...Any thoughts?

Comment: try putting it all on one line, I'm not sure the parser supports \ for line continuation

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, thanks but it didn't help. Same thing, nothing happens. Maybe geoserver is just not reading that file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Andrea Aime answered it in the geoserver-users list](https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/geoserver-users/thread/CA%2BnxMTt0e_YTbijBG91QqJShhJVPEcAAXiNsh9V0A%3DU9KmJD5Q%40mail.gmail.com/#msg36674810), which I quote here for the records:

> the syntax looks like a WKT2 representation, which GeoServer is not
>   able to parse (code contributions or funding to get it going more than
>   welcomed). I believe you'll have to rewrite it using WKT compatible
>   sytanx instead (I'm not aware of an automatic conversion tool, if
>   anyone knows one, could you please let us know?)

Pyproj CRS' `to_wkt()` returns a WKT2 string by default, to change that we may use the `version` argument; from `CRS.to_wkt` docs:

```
to_wkt(...) method of pyproj.crs.CRS instance
    Convert the projection to a WKT string.

    Version options:
      - WKT2_2015
      - WKT2_2015_SIMPLIFIED
      - WKT2_2018
      - WKT2_2018_SIMPLIFIED
      - WKT1_GDAL
      - WKT1_ESRI


    Parameters
    ----------
    version: str
        The version of the WKT output. Default is WKT2_2018.

    Returns
    -------
    str: The WKT string.
```

Indeed, I had GeoServer successfully reading my projection using `WKT1_ESRI`:

```
>>> merc.to_wkt('WKT1_ESRI')                                                                                       
'PROJCS["unknown",GEOGCS["GCS_unknown",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["unknown",2439700.0,0.0]],PRIMEM["Reference meridian",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'
```

and with `WKT1_GDAL` too -- after a small editing: remove the `EXTENSION` field, GS doesn't like it.

---

**Update**

For further info about WKT versions:

- https://www.gdal.org/wktproblems.html
- http://www.geoapi.org/3.0/javadoc/org/opengis/referencing/doc-files/WKT.html